# How can I plot the mean of a feature in a barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have followed barplot example:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/violin_data.csv")

g <- ggplot(df, mapping = aes(forcats::fct_infreq(sex), fill = as.factor(size))) +
  geom_bar(colour = "white") + coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0("n=", ..count..)), stat='count', 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
g
```

Which gives me:

[image]

What I want is the mean of the size from the Female and the Male:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the mean of values by size, you could create a `mean` column first,

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(size)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fct_infreq(sex))) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(size)), colour = "white") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("mean = %.2f",mean)), stat="count", position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

---

Previous answer:
When you set the aesthetics with `aes` inside the `ggplot` function, it will affect all future `geom_` commands, but here you should not use the same `aes` for `geom_bar` and `geom_text`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(fct_infreq(sex))) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(size)), colour = "white") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0("mean=", ..count..)), stat="count", position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. What I want is not the mean of the counts, I want the mean of the size (1,2,3,4,5,6) in the single characteristic.